# Duplicate id using JPA2 and testing

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring, ora-00001

I'm a bit confused right now :-S

I'm working on a project that uses JPA2, Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate 3.6.0 Final. We have the following code (only relevant classes)

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 36)
    protected String id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    protected User() {
        id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}


@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(User user) throws PreexistingEntityException, Exception {
        try {
            em.persist(user);

        } catch (EntityExistsException ex) {
            logger.error("User " + user + " already exists.", ex);
            throw new PreexistingEntityException("User " + user + " already exists.", ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred:", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}



@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testDaoContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class UserDaoTest {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertUserExistingID() {
        User user = User.valueOf("1");
        user.setFirstname("DUMMY");
        user.setName("CRASH");
        logger.debug(user);
        try {
            userDao.create(user);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        } catch (PreexistingEntityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.debug("id = " + user.getId());

        User retrieved = userDao.find(user.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(user.getId(), retrieved.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals("DUMMY", retrieved.getFirstname());
        Assert.assertEquals("CRASH", retrieved.getName());
    }

}
```

Now, when I run the test (I know, it's not a real unit test) with rollback set to false, I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into PV_UMDB.USERS (CREATION_DT, CREATION_USR, MODIFICATION_USR, MODIFICATION_DT, VERSION, BIRTHDAY, EMAIL, FAX, FIRSTNAME, INTERNAL, MOBILE, NAME, PHONE, PICTURE, STAFF_NO, STAFF_NO_KBC, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [PV_UMDB.USERS_PK]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:471)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:515)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:183)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:406)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:90)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (PV_UMDB.USERS_PK) violated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10768)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 34 more
```

If I use rollback, then the test passes, which of course is incorrect.

Now, is there a good solution?

Thanks for your help

BB
Peter

Comment: What is exactly a problem, what is an expected behaviour? Also what does `User.valueOf()` mean?

Comment: @axtavt: The problem is that the exception which I think I should get (PreexistingEntityException) is eaten by Spring due to its AOP and thus my test itself is useless. The valueOf() method is a way to return an object with a certain ID since normally the ID is an UUID.

Comment: @Peter: How did you get `SessionFactory` in the test?

Comment: Your test case drives my crazy: what do you want to test: that the PreexistingEntityException is thrown or that the user is stored?

Comment: By the way, replace the handling of Exception in your DAO by RuntimeException, because there is no other checked exception thrown by the entity manager, so you do not need to handel and **declare** it.

Comment: @axtavt: the SessionFactory is injected via the spring annotations in the test

Comment: @Ralph: The test is to see if a User with an existing ID is stored, the PreexistingEntityException is thrown. The code was generated by Netbeans btw, and I haven't fine tuned it. I first wanted to write a test :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on `EntityExistsException` thrown by `persist()`.

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html):

> `EntityExistsException` - if the entity
>   already exists. (If the entity already
>   exists, the `EntityExistsException` may
>   be thrown when the persist operation
>   is invoked, or the
>   `EntityExistsException` **or another
>   `PersistenceException` may be thrown at
>   flush or commit time.**)

In your case, you get another exception thrown at the commit time. If you replace

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
```

with

```
em.flush();
```

you can catch a `PersistenceException` thrown at the flush time (I'm not sure why it doesn't work the same way with `SessionFactory`).

Answer (score 0):

> The test is to see if a User with an
>   existing ID is stored, the
>   PreexistingEntityException is thrown.

The general pattern for checking a exception is:

- Junit4: @Test(excpect=ExcpectedException.class), or
- JUnit3 or when the easy pattern is not working:

psydocode for JUnit3

```
try { 
  invokeExceptionThrowingMethod();
  fail("ExceptionX expected");
} catch(ExcpectedException e) {
  //expected - do nothing
}
```

I strongly belive, that if you write your test case more clear, than you will find the bug.

**edited**

In your case, you need the second variant, because the test must not accept an exception from the first user creation.

```
@Test
public void testInsertUserExistingID()         
       //(See my comment to your question about throwing Exception)
       throws Exception{
    User user = User.valueOf("1");
    user.setFirstname("DUMMY");
    user.setName("CRASH");

    try {
        userDao.create(user);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        fail("PreexistingEntityException expected");
    } catch (PreexistingEntityException e) {
        //Thats what is execpected
    }
}
```

**Anyway: axtavt is right**